# "You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first" when I tried to attach the Rails container on Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to attach the Rails container with Docker but they said "You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first"

But I executed `$docker ps` once, they are working, but if I tried to execute `$docker attach [rails container name]`, it's gone.

I tried `$docker restart [rails container name]`, but it's not working like below.

Anyone knows how should I resolve this problem??

I use MacOS10.13.6、and docker version is 19.03.8, and ruby version on Docker is 2.4.5.

```
$ docker-compose build
db uses an image, skipping

Building web

Step 1/8 : FROM ruby:2.4.5
 ---> a14928bdfa34
Step 2/8 : RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 440899707638
Step 3/8 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b298382e3fca
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1bd9c799818c
Step 5/8 : COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a7ad7441bfe
Step 6/8 : COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 916a18caba9f
Step 7/8 : RUN bundle install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c03081abfed0
Step 8/8 : COPY . /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2a7496170af
Successfully built e2a7496170af
Successfully tagged fullstack_web:latest

$ docker-compose up -d
fullstack_db_1 is up-to-date
Starting fullstack_web_1 ... done

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e117a2a95ad3        fullstack_web       "bundle exec rails s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   fullstack_web_1
954bc6c3627f        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      fullstack_db_1

$ docker attach fullstack_web_1
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                 NAMES
954bc6c3627f        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   fullstack_db_1

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                 NAMES
e117a2a95ad3        fullstack_web       "bundle exec rails s…"   16 minutes ago      Exited (1) 18 seconds ago                         fullstack_web_1
954bc6c3627f        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes               3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   fullstack_db_1

$ docker restart fullstack_web_1
fullstack_web_1

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e117a2a95ad3        fullstack_web       "bundle exec rails s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   fullstack_web_1
954bc6c3627f        mysql:5.7           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp      fullstack_db_1

$ docker attach fullstack_web_1
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

More Information

I tried to use "pry-byebug" on Docker container.
So I added "gem pry-byebug" in my Gemfile.
Then after that, I tried to attach rails container like above.

And this is Github↓
bit.ly/2U5ulA6

Comment: I don't see a `CMD` line in the output you show; how does your application start?  Can you include your Dockerfile and other parts of a [mcve] in the question?

Comment: Mr.David, Thank you for your comment. I add "More Information" section in my question.